# Drop caps change position when images are floated right

Tags: html, css, css-float

I am trying to replicate as closely as possible the look of a book in html that includes drop caps floated left and multiple images that are floated right. Everything works fine with 1 image floated right...but the drop caps change position when more than 1 image is floated right. It looks fine in my editor but not in any browser I've tested. I've tried everything I can think of...
The css:

```
body {
background:#9CF;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

h1 {
font-family:Lusitana, serif;
font-size:14px;
letter-spacing:.3em;
}

h2 {
font-family:'Crimson Text', serif;
font-size:12px;
letter-spacing:.3em;
font-weight:400;
}

p {
font-family:'Crimson Text', serif;
font-size:12px;
line-height:16px;
font-weight:400;
margin-top:0;
color:#000;
text-align:justify;
}

.dropcap {
font-family:'Crimson Text', serif;
font-size:310%;
line-height:65%;
margin-top:3px;
margin-right:6px;
color:#333;
display:inline-block;
float:left;
}

#container {
background:#FFF;
height:698px;
width:452px;
padding:30px 30px 40px;
}

#imagediva {
height:229px;
width:127px;
background:rgba(200,255,255,0.5);
margin:0 0 10px 20px;
}

#imagedivb {
height:180px;
width:268px;
background:rgba(200,255,255,0.5);
margin:0 0 10px 20px;
}

.floatright {
clear:right;
float:right;
}

h1.short,h2.short {
line-height:0;
}
```

The html

```
<div id="container">

<div class="floatright" id="imagediva"></div> 
<div class="floatright" id="imagedivb"></div> 

<h1 class="short">First Flight</h1>
<hr size="1" noshade>
<h2 class="short">1929</h2>
<br> 
<p><span class="dropcap">W</span>alter’s first flight experience was in a two seater     open biplane when he was ten years old. His father hired a pilot take Walter and his cousin Victor Azevedo on a flight around the Oakland, CA. airport, the same airport from which Amelia Earhart would begin her ill fated attempt to circumnavigate the globe six years later in 1937.
</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This **[Fiddle](http://goo.gl/atJD9T)**

Give absolute position to the paragraph tag and also give some width to it. This will solve your problem.

```
body {
background:#9CF;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

h1 {
font-family:Lusitana, serif;
font-size:14px;
letter-spacing:.3em;
}

h2 {
font-family:'Crimson Text', serif;
font-size:12px;
letter-spacing:.3em;
font-weight:400;
}

p {
font-family:'Crimson Text', serif;
font-size:12px;
line-height:16px;
font-weight:400;
margin-top:0;
color:#000;
text-align:justify;
position: absolute;
width: 300px
}

.dropcap {
font-family:'Crimson Text', serif;
font-size:310%;
line-height:65%;
margin-top:3px;
margin-right:6px;
color:#333;
display:inline-block;
float:left;
}

#container {
background:#FFF;
height:698px;
width:452px;
padding:30px 30px 40px;
}

#imagediva {
height:229px;
width:127px;
background:rgba(200,255,255,0.5);
margin:0 0 10px 20px;
}

#imagedivb {
height:180px;
width:268px;
background:rgba(200,255,255,0.5);
margin:0 0 10px 20px;
}

.floatright {
clear:right;
float:right;
}

h1.short,h2.short {
line-height:0;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your reply Vikas, but absolute positioning will not allow the text to wrap around the images and ignores margins (each page contains a full page of text, I did not include all the text in the example for the sake of brevity). What am I missing?

Comment: I stumbled upon a solution to this problem. By giving the first paragrah <br> a class of clear: both; everything falls into place correctly, gives me control of margins on the images, text stays within the flow of the page and the code validates. Does anyone see a problem with this, or have a better fix? My thanks Vikas and anyone else who tried to help with this.

Comment: Actually on further checking...putting a "clear both" class on the last paragraph closing tag on the page works just as well.

Comment: I just set up a page see this http://jsfiddle.net/gjruL/1/ but still no success from my end..